# How do I add a tooltip to a TableColumn item?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

[image]

This is my current Display board and I would like to add a tooltip on top of the Items menu. How do I do this since itemNameCol.setTooltip is undefined? My code is below.

```
TableView<AuctionItem> table = new TableView<AuctionItem>(); 
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setMinSize(500, 510);
        
        TableColumn<AuctionItem, String> itemNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Items");
        itemNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<AuctionItem, String>("name"));
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text, please ..

Comment: i deleted the plain text screenshot and replaced it with the code

Comment: do you mean to the header of the column? If so, try to grab the TableColumnHeader (it's the node responsible for showing it) via the column's Styleable role (column.getStyleableNode) after it's attached to its skin

Comment: Yes, I want to attach a tooltip to the "Items" header item.

Comment: then go ahead :)

Comment: Isn't TableColumnHeader a completely separate class?

Comment: yeah, but that's a implementation detail that you don't need to know - read the api doc of TableColumn, find the method I suggested and use it to set the Tooltip on the Node that's returned. When stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected